# How is it a concave function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have the following function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{1+x+y}$$
where $x\geq 0, y\geq0$. The Hessian of the above function is given as follows:
$$\left[\matrix{-\frac{2y(y+1)}{(1+x+y)^3} & \frac{1+x+y+2xy}{(1+x+y)^3}\\ \frac{1+x+y+2xy}{(1+x+y)^3} & -\frac{2x(x+1)}{(1+x+y)^3}}\right]$$
I think its determinant is not always greater than zero so how to prove that the above function is concave? Thanks in advance.

I read about this function in a research paper. In that paper they say that $f(x,y)$ is a concave function because $-2y(y+1)(1+x+y)^2<0$ and determinant of the Hessian matrix is $\geq 0$ (In that paper the (second column and first row) and (first column and second row) entries of the Hessian matrix are written as $\frac{2xy}{(1+x+y)^3}$ instead of $\frac{1+x+y+2xy}{(1+x+y)^3}$) therefore I am confused.

I have even tried checking $$[v_1\quad  v_2] \left[\matrix{-\frac{2y(y+1)}{(1+x+y)^3} & \frac{1+x+y+2xy}{(1+x+y)^3}\\ \frac{1+x+y+2xy}{(1+x+y)^3} & -\frac{2x(x+1)}{(1+x+y)^3}}\right]\Bigg[\matrix{v_1 \\v_2}\Bigg]$$ test for any real values of $v_1$ and $v_2$. The answer of the above matrix multiplication results in (ignoring the denominator since it is always positive) $$-y(y+1)v_1^2+(1+x+y+2xy)v_1v_2-x(1+x)v_2^2$$ I am not sure if it is always negative. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @AustinWeaver I read about this function in a research paper. In that paper they say that $f(x,y)$ is a concave function because $-2y(y+1)(1+x+y)^2<0$ and determinant of the Hessian matrix is $\geq 0$ (In that paper the (second column and first row) and (first column and second row) entries of the Hessian matrix are written as $\frac{2xy}{(1+x+y)^3}$ instead of $\frac{1+x+y+2xy}{(1+x+y)^3}$) therefore I am confused.

Comment: Please add these details to your question.

Comment: @AustinWeaver added to the question

Comment: @AustinWeaver I have checked the upper level set of the above function for different values in WA. According to those plots the function has convex upper level sets. Is there something wrong with my Hessian matrix?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time that a completely fallacious claim of convexity/concavity makes it into a paper. Heck I can't tell you how many times I've had to argue with people who were certain that $f(x,y)=xy$ was convex. "Oh, but what if x,y are nonnegative?" No, not even there, either. How frustrating for the readers of these papers!

Answer (score 2):

The function is not concave.

On the line $(t,t)$, with $t \ge 0$, we have $\phi(t)=f(t,t) = {2t^2 \over 1+2t}$, and 
a bit of work shows that $\phi''(t) = {2 \over 8 t^3+ 12 t^2 +6 t +1} > 0$, so,
in fact, $f$ is strictly convex on this line.